# Extracting info from a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary object called `obj_1` and it's values are shown like this:

```
{u'd':{u'results': [{u'Desc':u'This is a description...',
                    u'Title':u'This is a title...',
                     u'data': {u'Url': u'www.site.com'}},

                   {u'Desc':u'This is a description...', 
                    u'Title':u'This is a title...',
                     u'data': {u'Url': u'www.site.com'}}]
}}
```

This is decoded json (decoded using the `requests` module decoder). How do I extract the `u'Title'` values and the URL values only? I haven't seen any dictionary types like this in any of the tutorials.

Comment: This doesn't look like a valid Python dictionary. SO's syntax highlighting shows you there's something inconsistent.

Comment: This is not correct dictionary and also not correct json.

Comment: @eumiro sorry fixed the code I have a massive output and in trying to show the format I messed it up a bit.

Comment: @adohertyd It is still invalid

Comment: change 'u'...' to u'...' in the Title rows - the ' at the beginning is too much

Comment: @jamylak and everyone else! Apologies, definitely correct now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming tyour "obj_1" really looks like this:

```
obj_1 = {u'd':{u'results': [{u'Desc':u'This is a description...',
                            u'Title':u'This is a title...'},

                            {u'Desc':u'This is a description...', 
                            u'Title':u'This is a title...'}]
        }}
```

Then its a as simple as:

```
titles = [d['Title'] for d in obj_1['d']['results']]
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, please see the edit to my question. I also want the URL's, which are in another nested section. Would that be  `page_urls = [d['Url'] for d in obj_1['d]['results']['data']`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> obj_1 = {u'd':{u'results': [{u'Desc':u'This is a description...',
...                     u'Title':u'This is a title...',
...                      u'data': {u'Url': u'www.site.com'}},
... 
...                    {u'Desc':u'This is a description...', 
...                     u'Title':u'This is a title...',
...                      u'data': {u'Url': u'www.site.com'}}]
... }}
>>> [(x[u'Title'], x[u'data'][u'Url']) for x in obj_1[u'd'][u'results']]
[(u'This is a title...', u'www.site.com'), (u'This is a title...', u'www.site.com')]
```